# How to $lookup users in Meteor aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am aggregating in **Meteor** using [meteorhacks:aggregate](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate) package, is there anyway that I can lookup to **users** collection?

For example i have to group the messages (Messages collection) based from a range of date and I need to get the senders (Users collection) information.

heres my code:

```
return Messages.aggregate([
  {$match: {$gte: <date from>, $lt: <date to>}},
  {$group: {_id: { year: {$year: "$createdAt"}, month: {$month: "$createdAt"}, day: {$dayOfMonth: "$createdAt"} },},},
  {$sort: {'_id.year': - 1, '_id.month': -1, '_id.day': -1}},
  {$lookup: {from: "Meteor.users", localField: 'senderUser_id', foreignField: '_id', as: 'users_docs'}},
]);
```

Can anyone figure out what I did wrong? Any advice/help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think that should be just `from: "users"` not `from: "Meteor.users"`. Also make sure that you are using Meteor >= 1.4 because lookups are not supported in older versions.

Comment: when i use from: "users" it gives me error saying that theres already a collection named users